# Bootstrap 4 responsive button size

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Is there a way in Bootstrap 4 to add the class 'btn-sm' (small button) when in the media-breakpoint-xs?

I'd like to the buttons to be default size except in xs screens where I'd like them to automatically switch to btn-sm.

Comment: Add the class to the element and apply styles within a media query.

Comment: The class is bootstrap default, by adding the class to the element in the code, the button would get those styles regardless of the current breakpoint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create responsive buttons in bootstrap3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709917/how-to-create-responsive-buttons-in-bootstrap3)

Comment: @user1394625 That's why the flag states `Possible`. Don't assume I downvoted your question only because I flagged it as a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assign `.btn` the `.btn-sm` sizing using the media-breakpoint-between mixin...

```
/* change all .btn to .btn-sm size on xs */
@include media-breakpoint-between(xs,sm){
  .btn {
      @include button-size($btn-padding-y-sm, $btn-padding-x-sm, $font-size-sm, $btn-border-radius-sm);
  }
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/FoEUO7XCDU

---

**Update - Bootstrap 4.1**
This `button-size` mixin has changed slightly to:

```
@include media-breakpoint-between(xs,sm){
  .btn {
      @include button-size($input-btn-padding-y-sm, $input-btn-padding-x-sm, $font-size-sm, $line-height-sm, $btn-border-radius-sm);
  }
}
```

Comment: thats exactly it! Thanks for taking the time to read the question

Comment: @Mark you can add it to any .scss file in you project but you may also have to import bootstrap-grid.scss and _buttons.scss so it knows what 'xs','sm','$btn-padding-y-sm' (and the other variables) mean. Such as:

@ import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-grid.scss";
@ import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_buttons.scss";

All this stuff may vary depending on how you set up your ng2 project

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap 4 this can be achieved using the utility classes alone.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary d-flex justify-content-center d-md-table mx-auto">Book a demo</a>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want in my case, thanks Man :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a button responsive, you need to make its text responsive.

You can use vw (Viewport Width) for font size:

```css
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .responsive-content {
    font-size: 6vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="responsive-content btn btn-primary">
  responsive button
</button>
```

Now you can resize the screen to see the effect.